# Converting HTTP to HTTPs

Tags: tomcat, https

We have an application which is hosted in tomcat with HTTP. Now we want to change the protocol to HTTPs. Can you please let me know on what steps to follow to implement the HTTPs protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Basically follow the steps here:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

if you're using vanilla tomcat, essentially you just need to install the certs and modify the existing/add a new entry in the server.xml file to configure a ssl connector